# Lumen can't set custom validation rules

Tags: laravel, lumen

I try this code to set custom validation messages, but with no effect -

```
class TestController extends Controller
{
    public function submit(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request,
            [
                'items' => 'required'
            ],
            [
                'items.required' => 'test test'
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

But on error I got this response -

```
{
  "error": "The given data failed to pass validation."
}
```

What wrong with this code?

UPD:

Earlier I edit `App\Exceptions\Handler` to put errors(in API response) in specific format -

```
{
  "error": "123"
}
```

This code is reason that validation errors not shown -

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    return response([
        'error' => $e->getMessage()
    ], 500);
}
```

I update  `Handler::render` method regarding to this purpose

```
public function render($request, Exception $e) {
    $response = parent::render($request, $e);

    if (isset($response->exception) and !empty($response->exception)) {
        return response(['error' => $response->exception->getMessage()], 500);
    } else {
        return parent::render($request, $e);
    } 
}
```

But I think I need to improve this code.

Comment: Can you just put the exception handle file back in its original state without your modifications? Just to make sure: Your main problem is that it is not showing your custom error message, right?

Comment: Yes, I need to show my \Exceptions in response as {"error":}  field. But it's good to put also validation errors there.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37038229/laravel-5-2-validation-with-api/37725464#37725464

Answer (score -1):

It seems you mixed validation `rules` and `messages`.
The `validate` method takes 3 parameter: `request`, `rules`, `messages`.

Please try this:

```php
public function submit(Request $request)
{
    $rules = [
        'items' => 'required',
        'otheritems' => 'required',
    ];

    $messages = [
        'items.required' => 'Error: Please enter something.',
        'otheritems.required' => 'Otheritems are also required',
    ];

    $this->validate($request, $rules, $messages);
}
```

The latest Lumen version always gives back JSON, see [documentation](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/master/validation):

> The `$this->validate` helper will **always** return JSON responses with the relevant error messages when validation fails. If you are not building a stateless API that solely sends JSON responses, you should use the full Laravel framework.

**Update regarding `error`:**
The given result by Lumen looks like that.

```php
{"items":["Items are required"],"otheritems":["Otheritems are also required"]}
```

Each item that failed the validation gets an entry in your response. So your `error` bag, need to be a JSON array.

Custom exception `render` method:

```php
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    $response = parent::render($request, $e);

    if ($response->getStatusCode() == 422) {
        $renderResult = parent::render($request, $e);
        $returnResult['error'] = json_decode($renderResult->content(), true);
        $returnResult = json_encode($returnResult);

        return new Response($returnResult, $response->getStatusCode());
    } else {
        return parent::render($request, $e);
    }

}
```

Comment: I try this code, but with no effect. In first example as 3rd param I pass messages array, no mixing there.

Comment: I edit the question, add explanation, maybe you can help to improve resulting code. Many thanks!

Comment: @sharp Do you build a stateless API or a website? It it's not an app please consider using Laravel. Otherwise I'll check how to return `error` in your response.

Comment: @sharp I updated my post with a custom exception `render` method. Does that help?